# Tomcat 7 vs. ehCache Standalone Server (Glassfish) Configuration with RESTful Web Services

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

My requirements consist of using ehCache to send and store data via RESTful web service calls. The data can be stored in-memory or via the filesystem...

Never used ehCache before so I am having some issues deciding on which bundle to use.

Have downloaded the following bundles:

ehcache-2.6.2

ehcache-standalone-server-1.0.0

(1) What is the difference between the two?

It seems the ehcache-2.6.2 contains src and binaries, which essentially enables one to bundle it with their webapps (by putting the compiled jar or binaries inside the webapp's WEB-INF/lib folder). But it doesn't seem that it has support for Restful web services.

Whereas, ehcache-standalone-server-1.0.0 (comes with an embedded Glassfish server and has support for REST & SOAP) can be used to run as a standalone server. If I my answers to my own question are correct, then that means, I should just use the standalone server?

(2) My requirements are to setup ehCache (with REST support) on Tomcat 7. So, how could I setup ehCache on Tomcat 7 as a separate app with REST & SOAP support?

Thank you for taking the time to read this...

Answer (score 1):

thats right, the first package is to include ehcache into your own application (this application could also be just a REST Interface for the cache )

the second one bundels already an application server with it, because you need to run it on dedicated hardware which more memory, you need a shared cache for many webservers, or you dont have java client. .....

to run it on tomcat just download the [distribution modul](http://ehcache.org/downloads/destination?name=ehcache-server-1.0.0-distribution.tar.gz&bucket=tcdistributions&file=ehcache-server-1.0.0-distribution.tar.gz) which is a simple WAR file, which can be deployed to tomcat or any other webserver. a REST Interface is included.